# python http.client : How to make a POST call with multipart/form-data content-type in the body

Tags: python, python-3.x, postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to make a call to an end point which take a the content of being a json.

I tried this

```
    def upload():

        connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(self.url)
        headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        connection.request("POST", "/",body=json.dumps(self.myjson), headers)
```

The content of my json is something like this

```
{"file": { "version":"2.0", "path":"my path", "test": "content"}}
```

The problem is that when I use postman and upload the file directly it works. But when I tried that portion of the code I have this error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property 'file[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: `headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'};conn.request("POST", "/",json.dumps(self.myjson),headers)`

Comment: @bigbounty I made that change but I am still having the same problem

Comment: have you tried `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data`?