# Unable to Upload File through Spring boot REST API POST call from Python

Tags: java, python-3.x, spring-boot, python-requests

I am trying to upload File through POST REST API Call(Spring boot) from a python script as wanted to automate some batch job.
But getting Error "Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile' for property 'file': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]..

python code :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
from pathlib import Path


headers={'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

fp = 'C:/inputs/inputfile.txt'
files = {'file': open(fp, 'rb')}

payload = {
    'integrator': 1,
    'version': 2, 
    'file': files
}


resp = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/upload/text", params=payload, headers=headers , files=files)
print (resp.text)
print ("status code " + str(resp.status_code))
```

My API code base( Java Springboot REST API) :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload/text", consumes = MediaTypes.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public List<String> uploadText(
    // @formatter:off
        @ModelAttribute
        TextUploadModel uploadModel,
        Principal principal
    // @formatter:on
    ) throws Exception {
        String userName = principal.getName();

        return service.uploadTextFile(uploadModel, userName);
    }
```

TextUploadModel.java is a POJO with String integrator, String version and MultipartFile file.
I found similar SOF post [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883704/python-http-client-how-to-make-a-post-call-with-multipart-form-data-content-ty)

Comment: have you tried `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may have to do with the definition of the `payload` dictionary, you are including the `file` parameter there, and it is very likely causing that parameter to be considered as `String` by Spring, because [every parameter included in the `params` argument is appended to the query string of the `Request`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/).

Please remove the `file` key from `payload`:

```py
payload = {
    'integrator': 1,
    'version': 2
}
```

Your file uploads information is being provided in the `files` arguments: `requests` will take care of placing every parameter type in the right location, setting the `Content-Type`, and establishing the appropriate multipart boundaries.

Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299889/how-to-post-multipart-list-of-json-xml-files-using-python-requests), it provides good advice about how to deal with `requests` multipart file uploads.

Comment: it indeed helped me and resolved the issue. Thanks! Just to providing logical conclusion to the post. As suggested I did 2 changes 1) done away from setting content type in the header and 2) removed files section for payload and the problem solved!

Comment: You are welcome @lifeline2, and thank you very much for the comments. That is great! I am happy to hear that you managed to solve the problem!!